# PSI WCF New-WebServiceProxy

Tags: wcf, web-services, powershell, psi

## Motivation:

As we can read in [Project Server Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee767687.aspx)

> The SOAP-based ASMX interface for web services in the PSI is still available in Project Server 2013, but is deprecated.

## As-Is

I have some PowerShell client snippets that I use to interact with Project Server. The standard way to communicate with the server are PSI ASMX web services.

## To-Be

I would like to refactor the snippets to the standard of using PSI WCF web services.

## Result

For example the following simple code works fine:

```
$Passwd = Get-Content $home\Documents\Password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PsCredential -argumentlist "user_name",$Passwd
$PWAUrl = "http://project_server_name/PWA"
$ProjSvcURL = $PWAUrl + "/_vti_bin/PSI/Project.asmx?wsdl"
$ProjSvcProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $ProjSvcURL -credential $Credential
$projDataSet = $ProjSvcProxy.ReadProjectList()
$projDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

but the simple conversion:

```
$Passwd = Get-Content $home\Documents\Password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PsCredential -argumentlist "user_name",$Passwd
$PWAUrl = "http://project_server_name/PWA"
$ProjSvcURL = $PWAUrl + "/_vti_bin/PSI/ProjectServer.svc"
...
```

fails with the message:

> New-WebServiceProxy : The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

Here is IIS log excerpt:

> 2014-01-05 13:50:41 10.15.43.7 GET /PWA/_vti_bin/PSI/ProjectServer.svc - 80 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.5472) 401 1 2148074254 125
>
> 2014-01-05 13:50:41 10.15.43.7 GET /PWA/_vti_bin/PSI/ProjectServer.svc - 80 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.5472) 401 2 5 328
>
> 2014-01-05 13:50:41 10.15.43.7 GET /_vti_bin/PSI/ProjectServer.svc/ntlm - 80 user_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.5472) 400 0 0 140
>
> 2014-01-05 17:58:33 10.15.43.7 GET /PWA/_vti_bin/PSI/ProjectServer.svc - 80 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.5472) 401 2 5 312
>
> 2014-01-05 17:58:33 10.15.43.7 GET /PWA/_vti_bin/PSI/ProjectServer.svc - 80 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.5472) 401 1 2148074254 156
>
> 2014-01-05 17:58:33 10.15.43.7 GET /_vti_bin/PSI/ProjectServer.svc/ntlm - 80 user_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.5472) 400 0 0 109

It is interesting that I cannot find any examples of using WCF PSI with PowerShell.
Have anyone tried to do this?
Have anyone succeed?
Can anyone publish any snippet?

Comment: `Bad Request` is a response from your web server. What do its logs say about this?

Comment: I see no IIS event log records corresponding to this message. Is there any other event log that can contain expected events?

Comment: IIS usually logs to files, not the eventlog. Check the website configuration.

Comment: Added above. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same Problem as you do. Project Server Scripts using the asmx and wanting to port them to the WCF Service pendants.

After some digging I found the following MSDN Site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms488627(v=office.15).aspx#pj15_PSIRefOverview_PSI

On there you got this Picture, shedding some light onto the whole WCF SVC thing: They are there, just not where you would expect them to be...

https://app.box.com/s/tsi7150bgra3rpg4n6yu

I tried to call the Service - and it worked like a charm.

I hope this helps you too!

P.S. Apologies for the box link... don't have enough reputation yet to post images ;)